# Find specific number of things with Beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I know that the `find()` command finds only the first occurrence and that `find_all()` finds all of them. Is there a way to find a specific number?
If i want to find only the first two occurrences is there a method for that or does that need to be resolved in a loop?

Comment: You can use list slices. If you only want the first two, use `soup.find_all(...)[:2]`.

Comment: Hi @akira, can I kindly remind you to mark one of the solutions below as answer?

Answer (score 0):

##### If you are looking for first n elements:

As pointed out in comments, you can use `find_all` to find all elements and then select necessary amount of it with list slices.

```py
soup.find_all(...)[:n]  # get first n elements
```

Or more efficiently, you can use `limit` parameter of `find_all` to limit the number of elements you want.

```py
soup.find_all(..., limit = n)
```

This is more efficient because it doesn't iterate through the whole page. It stops execution after reaching to limit.

Refer to the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#limit) for more.

##### If you are looking for the n(th) element:

In this case you can use `:nth-child` property of css selectors:

```py
soup.select_one('span:nth-child(n)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selectors knowing the child position you need to extract. Let's assume the HTML you have is like this:

```html
<div id="id1">
   <span>val1</span>
   <span>val2</span>
   <span>val2</span>
</div>
```

Then you can select the first element by the following:

```py
child = div.select('span:nth-child(1)')
```

Replace 1 by the number you want

If you want to select multiple occurrences, you can concatenate the children like this:

```py
child = div.select('span:nth-child(1)') + div.select('span:nth-child(2)')
```

to get the first two children

`nth-child` selector can also get you the odd number of occurrences:

```py
child = div.select('span:nth-child(2n+1)')
```

where n starts from 0:

```
n: 0 => 2n+1: 1
n: 1 => 2n+1: 3
..
```

Edited after addressing the comment, thanks!